# bootstrap 4 center heading and right align button all in one row

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 with React. I'm trying to center a h4 and right align couple of buttons all in one row. I could get it done but the h4 text is not centered to the entire width. It is centered only to the space that is remaining after buttons are placed.

I would like to center the h4 element to the entire width while placing the buttons to the right all in one row.

May I know how to achieve this?

```
<div>
  <div className="float-right">
    <EditButton /> <DeleteButton />
  </div>
  <h4 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Application Name</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post a picture or something to better illustrate what you want to achieve? What I understand is that you want the `h4` in the center of the screen, and the buttons on the space on the right of the `h4`?

Comment: @IvanS95, yes thats correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm understanding you want something similar to this, you would have to first set a `display: inline` property to the `h4` so the buttons (which are inline by default) follow the heading, and then a `text-center` class will center everything; but I think you also want the heading itself to be at the center of the screen and the buttons at the right of it, correct?

```css
.buttons {
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

h4{
  right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h4 class="text-center">H4 Title</h4>

<div class="text-center">
  <h4 class="d-inline">H4 Title</h4>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
</div>


<div class="text-center mt-5 position-relative">
  <h4 class="w-100 text-center">
    H4 Title
  </h4>
  <div class="position-absolute buttons">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the third output is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can center text by using class `text-center` and right align button by using class `text-right`

where `container-fluid` is use for full width and `m-0 p-0` is `margin: 0; & padding: 0` for remove corner space.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid p-0 m-0">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h4 class="d-inline">i am H4</h4>
    <button class="d-inline float-right btn btn-info">Demo</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but this puts the h4 and buttons in seperate rows. I want all of them in one row

Comment: thanks now elements are in one row but if I add more buttons on the right the heading is pushed to the left. I would like heading to be remained center